# What's a convenient way of resolving a path /bar/foo/baz/../.. into /bar?

Tags: python

Is there a module capable of doing this, or should I write something myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's about this :

```
>>> os.path.normpath("/bar/foo/baz/../..")
"/bar"
```